# php - srand with min & max values? or PRNG alternatives?

Tags: php, function, math, random

How can you use srand with a set seed with min and max values? I need to create set of random numbers, that can be recreated. Or what other options are there?

Comment: I need to use a seed so that I can generate the same results

Comment: **use rand()**. don't you understand?

Comment: int rand ( int $min , int $max ) - Where do i define the seed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    srand(4.0); // seed the generator.
    $rand_number = rand($min, $max); // generate random number between $min and $max.
?>
```

nothing to it. Just use the same srand() value each time and you'll get the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: oh right thanks. got a bit confused there, as I was thinking srand was going to output the numbers